# Flatpak viber doesnot run on wayland

Tags: 20.04, wayland, flatpak

```
android@inspi:~$ flatpak run com.viber.Viber
QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread
sh: xdg-mime: command not found
```

Flatpak viber doesnot run in wayland on 20.04.